# A hello world widget for the CMV application

Tags: configurable-map-viewer

I am trying to build my first widget, for use in the Configurable Map Viewer (CMV) and I want to start with something basic.
I was wondering if there is a tutorial or a step by step guide to create a simple "Hello World" widget in the CMV application?

Comment: what is the configurable map viewer?

Comment: The configurable Map Viewer is a JavaScript mapping web app that can be easily configured or used as a boilerplate/starting point for basic map viewers. It's built using the ArcGIS API for JavaScript which includes the Dojo Toolkit. It also demonstrates best practices for modular design and OOP via classes in JS using dojo's great declare system.

Visit http://cmv.io for details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After briefly looking through CMV, it looks kind of like a wrapper for the ESRI/Dojo widgets.

I would suggest looking at ESRI's samples to get an idea of how those are implemented.  [Here](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jshelp/intro_custom_dijit.html) is their information on creating custom widgets.

Then once you're comfortable with that, I would look at CMV's [widget documentation](http://docs.cmv.io/en/1.3.3/widgets/) and see how they wrap around existing ESRI widgets.

Somewhere along the line, you should probably get a good feel for how the widgets are used and constructed with CMV.  After looking through a little of the [basemaps widget configuration](http://docs.cmv.io/en/1.3.3/configure/basemaps/) it looks like CMV takes JSON objects and implements them into a format that can be read into ESRI's JS API.

There doesn't seem to be a tutorial out there.  However, it looks like user's have submitted their [own widgets](https://github.com/cmv/cmv-contrib-widgets) to the repository so it would be worth a look through their code to see what they're doing, too.